# MVC loading multiple partial view dynamically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

I want to load partial view dynamically as below sample then i want call specified record with id.I can load partial view dynamically use `@Html.Partial()` but same partial view returns only first record  due to disuse id.How can i solve this issue?

1. HtmlContent?id=1
2. Gallery?id=3
3. ContactForm
4. HtmlContent?id=5

Comment: Show sample of your razor markup

Comment: its really.I asked previously but nobody replied.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17186424/partialview-cumulatively-adding-issue